# Vaadin flow 23 onload event on javascript not working

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am using Vaadin flow 23 (spring boot). I loaded a Javascript file into browser successfully but **onload** event on JS does not trigger. With Vaadin flow 14, it works fine.

**clientLocation.js:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
   console.log("load js file ==================== ok");
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   //do something here but it never triggers when page is loaded
   startTimer();
})
```

[image: log console]

**This is how I load JS file:**

[image]

File **mainview.java**

[image]

======== Updated: ===============

- Tried with **@JsModule, @JavaScript** but still does not work!

[image]

**client Log:**

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: How did you add the JavaScript file?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I updated my question. basically JS will be loaded when user first time hits to home page (MainView)

Comment: Can you try to use @JsModule

Comment: @SimonMartinelli still not working. Updated question

Comment: More likely this is a bug on vaadin. I submitted bug to Vaadin: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/14211

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

workaround solution is to add JS file into **index.html**.

https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/14211

[image]